# What is the BIOS key for lenovo G500?

Tags: bios

I am trying to enable intel VT through BIOS but can't access. 
I read that the small button next to power button can be used but a system restore is needed ... 
Is it safe or is there any other way to enter the BIOS?

Comment: Not all Lenovo's are the same, how about a model number?

Comment: Newer Lenovos have a very small button that's usually somewhat recessed... From an off state, simply press this button and your computer will either boot to the BIOS, or to a menu allowing you to choose the BIOS

Comment: Lost or Forgotten Passwords: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht036206

Comment: @ParrtMac that small button did do wonders ... finally got access to BIOS successfully :)

Comment: A classic trick is to hold down a key on the keyboard and power on the system, and keep holding that key until the operating system boot loader starts. This will, in 95% or more of the cases, lead to a "stuck key" error from the BIOS, which will tell you how to enter the BIOS setup.

Answer (score 5):

This answer was provided by ParrotMac in the  comments to the question.  His answer probably saved me a few minutes of searching all around for the right Function key to enter the bios, therefore I think his answer deserves to be in the answers provided.

The Lenovo G500 actually provides a small button just to the right of the power button with a curving arrow on it.  First shutdown the machine and then press the button.  The machine will turn on and you'll be able to choose between:
- Normal Start up
- BIOS
- Boot Sequence
- System Recovery

Or, in the words of ParrotMac:

> Newer Lenovos have a very small button that's usually somewhat recessed... From an off state, simply press this button and your computer will either boot to the BIOS, or to a menu allowing you to choose the BIOS

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this site](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht036045): there are mostly the keys <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>* or **" Access IBM** "

And yes, it is safe to try all of them out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it.
Lenovo (formerly IBM)

ThinkPad, IdeaPad, 3000 Series, ThinkCentre, ThinkStation

Press F1 or F2 after powering on the computer.
Older Lenovo products allow access to BIOS using Ctrl+Alt+F3, Ctrl+Alt+Ins, or Fn+F1.

Source: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm